# Computing a interpolating polynomial using python

Tags: python, math, polynomials

I have just written a newtinterp() method that implements newtons polynomial and horners formula.

How would i go about computing the interpolating polynomial p ∈ Pn, which interpolates the points (xi, f(xi)), i = 1, 2, . . . , n + 1 of a uniform partition of [−1, 1] for
n = 5, 10, 20, 100. Let zi, i = 1, 2, . . . , 201, equi-distributed points of [−1, 1].

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you've already written `newtinterp`, what's stopping you from applying it to points (xi, f(xi))?

Comment: thats what im asking, i just dont know how to do that